# R: Unexplainable behavior of ggplot inside a function

Tags: r, function, ggplot2

I have composed a function that develops histograms using ggplot2 on the numerical columns of a dataframe that will be passed to it.  The function stores these plots into a list and then returns the list.

However when I run the function I get the same plot again and again.

My code is the following and I provide also a reproducible example.

```
hist_of_columns = function(data, class, variables_to_exclude = c()){

    library(ggplot2)
    library(ggthemes)

    data = as.data.frame(data)

    variables_numeric = names(data)[unlist(lapply(data, function(x){is.numeric(x) | is.integer(x)}))]

    variables_not_to_plot = c(class, variables_to_exclude)



    variables_to_plot = setdiff(variables_numeric, variables_not_to_plot)

    indices = match(variables_to_plot, names(data))

    index_of_class = match(class, names(data))

    plots = list()

    for (i in (1 : length(variables_to_plot))){



          p  = ggplot(data, aes(x= data[, indices[i]], color= data[, index_of_class], fill=data[, index_of_class])) +
           geom_histogram(aes(y=..density..), alpha=0.3,
           position="identity", bins = 100)+ theme_economist() +
           geom_density(alpha=.2) + xlab(names(data)[indices[i]]) + labs(fill = class) + guides(color = FALSE)

          name = names(data)[indices[i]]

          plots[[name]] = p
    }

   plots

}


data(mtcars)

mtcars$am = factor(mtcars$am)

data = mtcars

variables_to_exclude = 'mpg'

class = 'am'

plots = hist_of_columns(data, class, variables_to_exclude)
```

If you check the list plots you will discover that it contains the same plot repeated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is strategy using `tidyeval` that does what you are after:

```
library(rlang)
library(tidyverse)

hist_of_cols <- function(data, class, drop_vars) {

    # tidyeval overhead
    class_enq <- enquo(class)
    drop_enqs <- enquo(drop_vars)

    data %>%
        group_by(!!class_enq) %>% # keep the 'class' column always
        select(-!!drop_enqs) %>% # drop any 'drop_vars'
        select_if(is.numeric) %>% # keep only numeric columns
        gather("key", "value", -!!class_enq) %>% # go to long form
        split(.$key) %>% # make a list of data frames
        map(~ ggplot(., aes(value, fill = !!class_enq)) + # plot as usual
                geom_histogram() +
                geom_density(alpha = .5) +
                labs(x = unique(.$key)))

}
hist_of_cols(mtcars, am, mpg)

hist_of_cols(mtcars, am, c(mpg, wt))
```

Comment: Your gather() function call has -am as an argument but I would like a general form (mtcars is only an example).  Moreover would it be possible to pass class as string -denoting the name of the class variable -- and drop_vars as a vector of strings corresponding to the names of the variables?   Finally can you explain why my code is malfunctioning?

Comment: Updated the issue in `gather()` The reason your current solution isn't working is because you are passing a vector via `data[, index]` to each `aes()` variable. Because `ggplot2` uses [lazyeval](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/lazyeval/vignettes/lazyeval-old.html) it is only looking up the actual values of that vector when you finish the loop. So it always sees the same vector value (because `i` is at its max) and thus you get a list of identical plots.

Answer (score 2):

Simply use `aes_string` to pass string variables into the `ggplot()` call. Right now, your plot uses different data sources, not aligned with ggplot's *data* argument. Below *x*, *color*, and *fill* are separate, unrelated vectors though they derive from same source but `ggplot` does not know that:

```
ggplot(data, aes(x= data[, indices[i]], color= data[, index_of_class], fill=data[, index_of_class]))
```

However, with *aes_string*, passing string names to *x*, *color*, and *fill* will point to *data*:

```
ggplot(data, aes_string(x= names(data)[indices[i]], color= class, fill= class))
```